# User registration using Spring Hibernate jsp mySQL

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

My Applicatoin is based on Spring 3, Hibernate, JSP and MySQL DB

While registering user, I want to check if username exists in DB. What is the best way to achieve this? can someone please provide example or reference to other posts?

### I have tried below stuff so far

On submit of a page, I have a service call in controller which returns user object (if username exists) otherwise null. i.e. "public User userService.getUser(userName)"

1. I dont know how to pass the message to jsp so posting this message
2. I am not sure if this is the correct approach? of not please suggest
   better one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make a `ajax` call to check the existence of user by calling the this function inside the controller, and display the appropriate message if the user already exist.

```
public boolean isUserExist(String userName)
{
return userDao.isExist(userName);
}
```

Comment: Ok. I browsed more and most of the posts suggest using Ajax. Since I am completely new to Ajax, i will learn it first. thanks...